# Xorg alternatives for Raspberry Pi architecture?

Tags: xorg

Could you list out some of the lightweight Xorg alternatives for the **ARMv6**?Xorg consumes a lot of resources.

Comment: We are waiting for a version of Xorg that [utilises the GPU effectively](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/98/40).

Comment: It's just taking 100MB of RAM and xterm is only thing running... crazy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Someone at the Arch forum did a summary a few years ago. I don't want to copy his experiences here, you can read that in [this topic](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=675960#p675960), but because links rot here is a list of systems he covered (for you to google about their current state)

Actively developed

- [Wayland Display Server](http://wayland.freedesktop.org/) (might not be suitable for the Pi)

Older

- [MicroXWin (archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20200130181628/http://volkspc.org/MicroXwin/)
- [DirectFB (archived)](https://web.archive.org/web/20170603093935/http://directfb.net/) ([Github](https://github.com/deniskropp/DirectFB))
- [Y Window System](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dsywindows/)
- [Xynth Window System](http://alperakcan.org/?open=projects&project=xynth)
- Fresco (Website not available)
- [Metisse](http://insitu.lri.fr/metisse/)
- [KDrive](http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/%7Ejch/software/kdrive.html) (or [TinyX](http://www.superant.com/smalllinux/tinyX01.html))

Comment: It might be useful to link to the project homepages (if they have one). Those links would be useful, hopefully for some time.

Comment: I suppose it would :)

Comment: Can they be compiled for the ARMv6?

Comment: MicroXWin has an explicit qemu arm build. DirectFB as a cross compiling tutorial on their wiki. I think wayland requires a more modern videocard.

Comment: Is the kernel module for MircoXwin built for 3.1.9 ?

Comment: Don't know, guess you should ask the developer. But the Pi works with other kernels than just 3.1.9 (openelec is currently using 3.2.24)

Comment: DirectFB site seems to be gone, the link now points to a website with porn links and IT jokes.