# X forwarding and GPU memory allocation

Tags: performance, ssh, xorg, display

I run my Raspberry Pi headless and typically use X forwarding to run applications.

I'm wondering what split I should use for allocating the RAM. I am not sure whether it is the server or the client's graphics memory which is "important" in this instance. Can I unallocate all the graphics memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asked [the same question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53707/how-does-x11-forwarding-work) on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange last week.

Apparently, you will need GPU resources on the machine with the graphic display (the X Server) and not the raspberry Pi that is doing the X11 forwarding (the Client). So you can allot minimal RAM for GPU on the Raspberry Pi.

What X11 forwarding does is forward GPU commands to the X Server on the client.

Answer (score 2):

X forwarding was not GPU accelerated the last time I checked.However it was announced on the official Raspberry twitter page that GPU acceleration is under consideration.

So X forwarding will still utilise your CPU for all the work.

As best practice for headless servers,

```
Give the CPU 224 MB and the GPU 32 MB
```

Hope this helps.

Also your question is almost similar to [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98/is-there-a-gpu-accelerated-xorg-server?rq=1) .

Comment: [SteveIrwin?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Irwin)

Comment: Yeah the crocodile hunter is back from dead working in a IT firm. :)